# fullpage.js - If 'scrolloverflow' is set to true can't scroll down to the next section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm using Fullpage.js with `scrolloverflow: true` and `autoscrolling: true`. Once I reach the bottom of the section with overflowing content it won't jump to the next one unless I click on the next navigation dot.

Tried to isolate the bug in a JS Bin, but I'm not able to reproduce it. No errors are found in the console, and I'm using the plugin's 2.8.1 version.

If you head to [this bin](http://jsbin.com/kegeyipuno/edit) you'll see that reaching the bottom of section 3 triggers the jump to section four. This does **NOT** happen on my end. Any ideas on what could it be or how to fix it?

My current settings to initialize fullpage.js are these:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  easingcss3: 'cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000)',
  navigation: true,
  navigationPosition: 'left',
  scrollOverflow: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this issue is a recent bug encountered when fullpage.js made the jump and started using iScroll.

Adding the following to the project's CSS seems to solve the problem:

```
.fp-scroller{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

More information [here](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2071).